# При получении post запроса из html формы и его обработки в java, русский язык не распознается

Tags: java, кодировка, servlet, html-form

Вот так выглядит моя форма:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Manager</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="/product/new" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="name">Название:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="description">Описание (необязательно):</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="photo">Фото (необязательно):</label>
            <input id="photo" name="photo" type="file"/>
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

когда я обрабатываю запрос в servlet api и пытаюсь получить значение параметров:

```
String name = req.getParameter("name");
```

Получается вот это: **ÐÐ¾ÑÐ¸Ñ**
При том что с английским языком все в порядке.

Я пытался перекодировать его через ByteBuffer но ничего не получилось
ПОМОГИТЕ

Comment: Код сервлета был бы кстати... [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125802/3129992) рассматривается такая-же проблема.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ссылку, все так просто решилось @XelaNimed

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо
@XelaNimed за ссылку на похожую проблему.
В общем перед тем как читать значения параметров запроса установите нужную вам кодировку:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: На мой взгляд проще прописать это в конфигурации, чем каждый раз "дёргать" свойства запроса...